# adjust slider to be fullscreen, no scrolling with elements centered around it

Tags: jquery, css, slider, positioning

I have a slider WMUslider, that I'm trying to make fullscreen, the image adjusts to the window size and the elements adjust to fit the aspect.  This should be doable in the css but I just can't get it to work.  It's the only thing on the page, right now you have to scroll down to see the whole image.  Any help I can get on this I'd really appreciate, I've been trying to do this for a while now and am starting to get very frustrated.

this is the site:

http://www.klossal.com/js/wmuSlider/demo/demo3.html

HTML:

```
<div class="wmuSlider example1">
<div class="wmuSliderWrapper" style="height:100%;">
<article>
<img src="http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/space_1_header.png" />
</article>
<article>
<img src="http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/space_2_header.png" />
</article>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* Demo */
.wmuSlider,
.wmuGallery {
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* mwuSlider */
.wmuSlider {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
.wmuSlider .wmuSliderWrapper {
display: none;
}
.wmuSlider .wmuSliderWrapper article {
position: relative;
text-align: center;
}
.wmuSlider .wmuSliderWrapper article img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

/* mwuGallery */
.wmuGallery .wmuGalleryImage {
position: relative;
text-align: center;
}
.wmuGallery .wmuGalleryImage img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

/* Default Skin */
.wmuGallery .wmuGalleryImage {
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.wmuSliderPrev, .wmuSliderNext {
position: absolute;
width: 40px;
height: 80px;
text-indent: -9999px;
background: url(http://klossal.com/js/wmuSlider/demo/images/sprites.png) no-repeat 0 0;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -40px;
z-index: 2;
}
.wmuSliderPrev {
background-position: 100% 0;
left: 20px;
}
.wmuSliderNext {
right: 20px;
}
.wmuSliderPagination {
z-index: 2;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
bottom: 0px;
}
.wmuSliderPagination li {
float: left;
margin: 0 5px 0 0;
list-style-type: none;
}
.wmuSliderPagination a {
display: block;
text-indent: -9999px;
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
background: url(http://klossal.com/js/wmuSlider/demo/images/sprites.png) no-repeat 0      
-80px;
}
.wmuSliderPagination a.wmuActive {
background-position: -10px -80px;
}

body{
background:#141414;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try 
`background-size: cover`
this will cover the page so it has the width of the screen.

Comment: for the ?div? or body where the image is located in

Comment: i think that will be the slider

Comment: I tried it on both, for the body nothing happened, for the slider the image just went to it's max resolution, it was much larger then the window size.

Comment: oh allright you also can try background-size: (and then the size you want to give the image) so it will fit in everyscreen without scrolling

Comment: So what I had been doing is setting max-width:100% and this kept the width to 100% of the window, no more or less, some how the height is continously going past the window height, this is teh main problem that won't go away.

Comment: hmm. you can try different height properties. height: 100%; min-height:100% max-height: 100% just try something like that

Comment: yea, I've been trying that, and either it goes over with height or only is about 4 px heigh, I really have no idea how to get this working at this point...

Comment: http://brice.lechatellier.com/code-design/wmuslider/  I've gone over page for the slider many times, and I can't find anything helpful there either.